# Keras how to use fit generator to train DL model with multiplte inputs (that has to be aligned)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have a deep learning model with three inputs:
videos, and for each video: title and list of categorical features.
So, what I train using `.fit`, it will look like this:

```
model.fit([X_videos, X_titles, X_features] , y)
```

However, due to memory limitations, I must use `.fit_generator`, which I never done before.
I have a dataframe which can be used to match the video with it's proper metadata:

```
df = video_path  encoded_title     f1 f2 f3 f4 .. f16
      path1        text1            0  1  1  0    1
      path2        text2            1  0  1  0    1
```

And so on
My question is - How can I create a generator out of this df?

While I found many example to generate videos, I couldn't find a way to generate multi-input data, while ensuring entries are aligned (meaning to ensure that each video will get his own title and features)

Attached is a scheme of my NN.

[image]

Comment: probably [this](https://github.com/AtrCheema/Miscellaneous_DL_Tutorials/blob/master/prepare_input_data_for_rnn_for_ts_prediction.ipynb) may help!

Comment: @AtherCheema Please see the following question here, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524078/python-cant-apply-fit-generator-to-keras-model-with-multiple-input