# Python can't apply fit_generator to keras model with multiple input

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have the following model - this is LSTM + CNN with 3 inputs.
[image]

And I built this generator function to train the model using fit_generator (based on this: [https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)):

```
class MultiInputDataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'

    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.batch_size = 8
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_classes = 5
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, 1, 3), dtype=object)
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=object)

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
        X_id = []
        x_features = df.iloc[id][et_cols].values #ET_COLS are 14 columns so I get 1X14 here
        x_text = df.iloc[id].text_col #x_text is 1X768
        x_vid = df.iloc[id].frame_col #x_vid is (3,244,244)
        
        X_id.append(x_features)
        X_id.append(x_text) 
        X_id.append(x_vid)
           
        X[i,] = X_id
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]

    y_mat = tf.convert_to_tensor(pd.get_dummies(y))
    return X, y_mat


training_generator = MultiModelDataGenerator(generator_partition['train'], generator_labels)
validation_generator = MultiModelDataGenerator(generator_partition['val'], generator_labels)
net = build_LSTMCNN_net()
net.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),'categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
net.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,)
                    use_multiprocessing=True)#,    workers=6)
```

And I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-669153f703e6> in <module>()
      
      net.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
--->                      validation_data=validation_generator,)
                          #use_multiprocessing=True)#,    workers=6)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I also tried several variations such as adding:

```
x_features = np.asarray(x_features).astype(object)
x_text = np.asarray(x_text).astype(object)
x_vid = np.asarray(x_text).astype(object)
```

Or `X[i,] = [X_id]` instead of `X[i,] = X_id`
But none worked
Any idea how to fix the problem?

Edited: When adding:

```
astype(np.float32)
```

and
`tf.convert_to_tensor(X)`

I get the error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
      net.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
--->                      validation_data=validation_generator,
                          use_multiprocessing=True,    workers=6)


/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
            dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
        ctx.ensure_initialized()
--->    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
```

Comment: What is the dtype of the numpy array?

Comment: @yudhiesh the type is object (see the lines:     X = np.empty((self.batch_size, 1, 3), dtype=object)
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=object))

Comment: Could you try ```astype(np.float32)``` instead of object?

Comment: @yudhiesh In that case I get the error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. For the line: `X[i,] = X_id`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create an array from a list that isn't shaped like a multi-dimensional array. When declaring ```X``` and ```Y``` did you set the ```dtype=np.float32```?

Comment: @yudhiesh Sorry I misread your comment. Whet trying `astype(np.float32)` I get: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).` For the line : `net.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,  validation_`data=validation_generator,)`.
And yes, I also suppose it is something with the dimension but I have no idea how to fix it since I thought I did defined it properly - any additional idea as to how it can be fixed?

Comment: Ok try ```tf.convert_to_tensor(Y)``` and ```tf.convert_to_tensor(X)``` as numpy is not working here.

Comment: @yudhiesh Still the same error: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).`  (also added to last edit)

Comment: Could you print out the shapes of ```X``` and ```Y```.

Comment: @yudhiesh Sure, y.shape is (8,) and X.shape is (8, 1, 3). `tf.convert_to_tensor` throws the error for X , and succeed for y

Comment: @yudhiesh any idea?

Comment: @okuoub Do you still get the same error if you use `fit` instead of `fit_generator`? And are you using `keras` or `tf.keras`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before solving the problem, **let's first summarize the dataset that you're working with.** Based on your description, I created an example `DataFrame` that might resemble yours

```
import pandas as pd

dataset_size = 500
train_idx,val_idx = train_test_split(range(dataset_size),test_size=0.2,) 

# create an example DataFrame that I assume will be resemble yours 
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'vids':np.random.randint(0,10000,dataset_size)})
# create feature columns 
for ind in range(14): example_df['feature_%i' % ind] = np.random.rand(dataset_size)
# each cell contains a list 
example_df['text'] = np.random.randint(dataset_size)
example_df['text'] = example_df['text'].astype('object')
for ind in range(dataset_size):example_df.at[ind,'text'] = np.random.rand(768).tolist()
# create the label column
example_df['label'] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=5,size=dataset_size)

# extract information from the dataframe, and create data generators 
all_vids = example_df['vids'].values
feature_columns = ['feature_%i' % ind for ind in range(14)]
all_features = example_df[feature_columns].values
all_text = example_df['text'].values
all_labels = example_df['label'].values
```

As you can see, the column `text` is a column of lists, in which each list contains 768 items. The column `labels` contains the labels of the examples, it doesn't matter whether you use one-hot encoding or other types of encoding, as long as its shape matches the shape of the output layer of the overall neural network model. The column `vids` is a column of `seed`s for generating random images on the fly.

---

**Solving the problem** (based on the above dataset)

You can use this syntax `return {'feature':features,'text':text,'vid':vid},y` for the method `__getitem__`, instead of stacking the three input arrays.

To explain this, let's first construct a toy model resembles yours

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense,Flatten,Add


def features_part(x):
    y = Dense(14)(x)
    y = Dense(10,activation='linear')(y)
    return y

def text_part(x):
    y = Dense(768)(x)
    y = Dense(10,activation='linear')(y)
    return y

def vid_part(x):
    y = Flatten()(x)
    y = Dense(10,activation='linear')(y)
    return y

input_features = Input(shape=(14,),name='feature')
input_text = Input(shape=(768,),name='text')
input_vid = Input(shape=(3,244,244,),name='vid')

feature_block = features_part(input_features)
text_block = text_part(input_text)
vid_block = vid_part(input_vid)
added = Add()([feature_block,text_block,vid_block])
# you have five classes at the end of the day 
pred = Dense(1)(added)
# build model
model = Model(inputs=[input_features,input_text,input_vid],outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='mae',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae'])
```

**The most important thing about this model is, I specified the names of the three input layers**

```
input_features = Input(shape=(14,),name='feature')
input_text = Input(shape=(768,),name='text')
input_vid = Input(shape=(3,244,244,),name='vid')
```

For this model, you can construct a generator like

```
# provide a seed for generating a random image 
def fn2img(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    # fake an image with three channels 
    return np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(3,244,244))


class MultiInputDataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, 
                 all_inds,labels, 
                 features,text,vid, 
                 shuffle=True):
        self.batch_size = 8
        self.labels = labels
        self.all_inds = all_inds
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
        self.features = features
        self.text = text
        self.vid = vid

    def __len__(self): 
        return int(np.floor(len(self.all_inds) / self.batch_size))


    def __getitem__(self,index):
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_indices = [self.all_inds[k] for k in indexes]
        features,text,vid,y = self.__data_generation(batch_indices)

        return {'feature':features,'text':text,'vid':vid},y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.all_inds))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self,batch_indices):
        # Generate data
        features = self.features[batch_indices,:]
        # note that you need to stack the slice in order to reshape it to (num_samples,768)
        text = np.stack(self.text[batch_indices])
        # since batch_size is not a super large number, you can stack here
        vid = np.stack([fn2img(seed) for seed in self.vid[batch_indices]])
        y = self.labels[batch_indices]

        return features,text,vid,y
```

as you can see, the `__getitem__` method returns a dictionary `{'feature':features,'text':text,'vid':vid},y`. The keys of the dictionary match the names of the three input layers. Moreover, the random images are generated on the fly.

In order to make sure everything works, you can run the script below,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense,Flatten,Add


# provide a seed for generating a random image
def fn2img(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    # fake an image with three channels
    return np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(3,244,244))


class MultiInputDataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self,
                 all_inds,labels,
                 features,text,vid,
                 shuffle=True):
        self.batch_size = 8
        self.labels = labels
        self.all_inds = all_inds
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
        self.features = features
        self.text = text
        self.vid = vid

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.all_inds) / self.batch_size))


    def __getitem__(self,index):
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_indices = [self.all_inds[k] for k in indexes]
        features,text,vid,y = self.__data_generation(batch_indices)

        return {'feature':features,'text':text,'vid':vid},y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.all_inds))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self,batch_indices):
        # Generate data
        features = self.features[batch_indices,:]
        # note that you need to stack the slice in order to reshape it to (num_samples,768)
        text = np.stack(self.text[batch_indices])
        # since batch_size is not a super large number, you can stack here
        vid = np.stack([fn2img(seed) for seed in self.vid[batch_indices]])
        y = self.labels[batch_indices]

        return features,text,vid,y


# fake a dataset
dataset_size = 500
train_idx,val_idx = train_test_split(range(dataset_size),test_size=0.2,)

# create an example DataFrame that I assume will be resemble yours
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'vids':np.random.randint(0,10000,dataset_size)})
# create feature columns
for ind in range(14): example_df['feature_%i' % ind] = np.random.rand(dataset_size)
# each cell contains a list
example_df['text'] = np.random.randint(dataset_size)
example_df['text'] = example_df['text'].astype('object')
for ind in range(dataset_size):example_df.at[ind,'text'] = np.random.rand(768).tolist()
# create the label column
example_df['label'] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=5,size=dataset_size)

# extract information from the dataframe, and create data generators
all_vids = example_df['vids'].values
feature_columns = ['feature_%i' % ind for ind in range(14)]
all_features = example_df[feature_columns].values
all_text = example_df['text'].values
all_labels = example_df['label'].values

training_generator = MultiInputDataGenerator(train_idx,all_labels,all_features,all_text,all_vids)

# create model
def features_part(x):
    y = Dense(14)(x)
    y = Dense(10,activation='linear')(y)
    return y

def text_part(x):
    y = Dense(768)(x)
    y = Dense(10,activation='linear')(y)
    return y

def vid_part(x):
    y = Flatten()(x)
    y = Dense(10,activation='linear')(y)
    return y

input_features = Input(shape=(14,),name='feature')
input_text = Input(shape=(768,),name='text')
input_vid = Input(shape=(3,244,244,),name='vid')

feature_block = features_part(input_features)
text_block = text_part(input_text)
vid_block = vid_part(input_vid)
added = Add()([feature_block,text_block,vid_block])
# you have five classes at the end of the day 
pred = Dense(1)(added)
# build model
model = Model(inputs=[input_features,input_text,input_vid],outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='mae',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae'])

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,epochs=10)

print(model.history.history)
```

Comment: Thanks! i get the error: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).` or `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).` in `model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,epochs=10)`. 
When I print the shapes of labels, features, text, vids in `__data_generation` I get ((8,), (8, 14), (8,), (8, 224, 224, 3)). These shape are correct right?

Comment: @okuoub you're welcome, I'm not sure why you got such error, did you get the error running the script in my post? The shapes are not the real problem, as long as they match the shapes of the `Input` layers.

Comment: @ meTchaikovsky Iur code runs perfectly, I just edited it slightly to fit my data , so I added (when df is a dataframe) : 
`all_features = df[_FEATS_COLS].values
all_text = df[_TEXT_COL].values #x_text is 1X768
all_vid = df[_FILENAME_COL]`
and in _data_generation:
`features = self.features[batch_indices, :]
text = self.text[batch_indices]
vids = vid_idx.apply(lambda x : fn2img(x)) 
vid = np.concatenate([x for x in vids])
y = self.labels[batch_indices]`
When fn2img is a function that takes a filename and returns 3X244X244 array

Comment: @okuoub Based on your description, I created an example dataframe that I guess resembles yours. Using the dataframe, my script still works. Please check out my updated post :)

Comment: @meTchaikovsy Thanks, 3 things I probably should've mention are:  1) applying `
all_vids = np.stack(example_df['vids'].apply(fn2img))` can't be done as it too heavy computationally, therefore I must do it "on the fly". 2) `text_columns` are not 768 columns, rather it is one columns, with each cell being a 1d list with 768 elements 3)`lables` is only one columns - Do I must to one-hot encode it?

Comment: @okuoub You're welcome, check out my updated post, I have updated the dataframe. No, you don't have to one-hot encode it, you can use other types of encoding as long as its shape matches the shape of the overall output layer, as I mentioned in my updated post.

Comment: Working Thanks! just 2 last question please: 1) Can you please explain why `np.stack` worked but `np.concatenate didnt?` 2) I got the warning `
`WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 768) for input Tensor("text_10:0", shape=(None, 768), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None).` , does it matter?

Comment: @okuoub You're welcome :) For the first question, since you want the shape of the input to be `(num_samples,3,244,244)`, you just can't use `np.concatenate`, please refer to the `numpy concatenate` documentation. For the second question, I can't tell why you got this warning, but from the name of the input tensor, I guess you run the code in a notebook for multiple times, maybe running the code in a fresh notebook will resolve the issue.

Comment: re the warning, it remains after restart the notebook. the shape of `text` in `_data_generation` is 8X1X768. Perhaps it should be 8X768?

Comment: @okuoub I didn't get the warning and I have no idea, since a batch of `text` is created using `np.stack`, the shape is just `(num_samples,768)` which I have tested on my Mac. I'm using `tensorflow 1.13.1` and `numpy 1.16.4` and python version `3.6.8`, maybe it is caused by the different versions of the packages you use?